# JodaTime DateTime and handling of Locales with AM/PM

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

Could please anybody explain to me, how DateTime works in regards to AM/PM ?

```
public DateTime(
        int year,
        int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth,
        int hourOfDay,
        int minuteOfHour,
        int secondOfMinute,
        int millisOfSecond,
        DateTimeZone zone) {
    super(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth,
          hourOfDay, minuteOfHour, secondOfMinute, millisOfSecond, zone);
}
```

I know that I could handle AM/PM via DateFormat and parsing string, but I'm interested in this method. I can't figure this out. Because DateTimeZone doesn't relate directly to Locale, Chronology does not too.

Do I have to manually change the hourOfDay based on AM/PM information into the 24 hours type ?

I'm working with a UI html form widget >> http request 6 parameters, based on Locale (y,m,d,h,m,AM/PM) / (y,m,d,h,m) >> now I'd like to create Date object from these 5/6 values via JodaTime's DateTime object. Is it possible without me manually having to convert (y,m,d,h,m,AM/PM) to (y,m,d,h,m) ?

Manually I'd do that like this

```
public static Date getDateSinceUTC2(Target orderBean, TimeZone tz) {

    int ap = orderBean.getDeadLineAmPm();
    int year = orderBean.getDeadLineYear();
    int month = orderBean.getDeadLineMonth();
    int day = orderBean.getDeadLineDay();
    int hour = orderBean.getDeadLineHour();
    int minute = orderBean.getDeadLineMinute();

    if (ap == 1) {
        hour += 12;
    }

    month++;

    DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID(tz.getID()));

    return new Date(dt.getMillis());
}
```

Comment: What do you mean in terms of "in regards to AM/PM"? What are you trying to do? I know Joda Time reasonably well, but I can't tell what you mean by "handling" AM/PM.

Comment: Edited, question is, does DateTime accept only the non-US date format ?

Comment: "date format" is a string representation, not a "uses AM/PM" concept.

Comment: You are saying that AM/PM exists only as a string representation that DateFormat is working with and the rest of JodaTime and Java's Date library doesn't work with that ?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that at all. I'm saying the idea of "non-US date format" is a string-based concept. Which fields you use is unrelated to locale, unless you're parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I would start off using `LocalDateTime` unless you've *actually* got a time zone.

But you could create either a `DateTime` or a `LocalDateTime` by giving it *any* hour, and then using:

```
// I'm assuming amPm is 0 for am and 1 for pm
result = original.withField(DateTimeFieldType.hourOfHalfDay(), hour)
                 .withField(DateTimeFieldType.halfDayOfDay(), amPm);
```

I think I'd *personally* probably perform the conversion to "hour of 24-hour day" myself though.

Comment: Ok, thank you Jon, that manual conversion I got in the Question is correct, right ?

Comment: +1 for persistence in mind-reading... but +1's carrying coals to Newcastle, I fear.

Comment: @Edgar: Not quite - it depends on what you get for midnight, which is typically represented as "12 am". In that case you'd want to *subtract* 12, but you want to leave midday ("12 pm") alone. Maybe using the fields is a better idea after all :)

Comment: This world is a hostile environment for machines :-)

Comment: @Edgar: If you think *this* is funky, you should look into the rest of the world of dates and times. It's plain crazy.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: joda-time-1.6.2 has DateTimeFieldType's hourOfHalfDay and halfDayOfDay methods argumentless

Comment: @Edgar: Sorry, that was a typo in where to put the brackets. I've edited - try again now.

Comment: But I put this into IF(AmPm) condition, right ? If I get the non-US values, this would set up also hourOfHalfday field and halfDayOfDay field, would it matter ?

Comment: @Edgar: Again, you shouldn't be concerned with "non-US" vs "US" - it's just a `LocalDateTime` or `DateTime` with appropriate values. Use that code if you've got hour-of-half-day and am/pm; don't use it otherwise.